# java.net.SocketException: Network subsystem is unavailable: create

Tags: network-protocols, socketexception

I'm trying to run liferay server on eclipse. Getting this error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Network subsystem is unavailable: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:255)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:205)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:380)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:566)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:449)
```

I used to run it many times but this exception occurs unexpectedly.
Also , I have google chrome and firefox browser , by the time the google chrome dose'nt work at all but firefox is working properly!
pLz help me to solve this problem.